# Strange Android APK app name on blackberry 10

Tags: android, blackberry, apk

I recently create / build android app using Ionic Framework. Works perfectly on Android phones. But when i install on Blackberry, it has strange app name such as @0x7f040000. The app itself seems fine. I've tried to convert into BAR file, signed the APK, etc still no luck. Been googling for several days with no progress at all. Any suggestion?

Comment: The app name of the APK when installed on BB10 has been subsequently fixed with some BB10 system update, but the apk2bar converter hasn't been updated, so when you install the bar file, you still get the strange app name. Always check the BAR file before submitting it to bb world...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several attempt, here my solution :

1. Convert your APK files to BAR using Blackberry APK Packager, i'm using [this](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/rpkg_with_apk_pkgr_tool.html). Check on Downloads > Command Line Tools
2. Change BAR file extension to ZIP. Extract.
3. Open META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, change the Entry-Point-Name to your desired app name
4. Open again Blackberry APK Packager, put edit MANIFEST.MF file to Custom Manifest. Click "Package" again
5. Done. Your BAR file now will display app name correctly

PS; im using Chrome BB10 App Manager to install on BB device

Comment: I've run into a similar issue however I cannot re-package the APK into a BAR file as I'm submitting to the Amazon App Store which seems to only accept APK files.  It sounds like the problem is with the Blackberry APK Packager incorrectly extracting the app name from the APK / Android Manifest.  Have you found a way to avoid this issue, perhaps by adjusting the Android Manifest or doing some other process that does not involve creating / hacking the BAR file?

Comment: I'm sorry, none other solution found yet, i'll write here if I get any clue about this :)

Comment: What I did is was just putting the changed Entry-Point-Name in the custom Manifest and clicking the "Add Custom Manifest Values (merge)" Button. This way I can get new changes in the Manifest and not overwrite them.

Comment: For the problems with .bar and .apk files in the comments: The Amazon App Store only accepts APK files if you want to use BAR files you have to to go over the blackberry world store! This way it works perfectly with BAR files.

Answer (score 2):

I found that changing the activity_name to the app name in the strings.xml file (.../res/values/strings.xml) will fix this.

Originally, this was set to @string/app_name for me. I'm guessing that blackberry doesn't follow string resources the way android does.